# Unexpected event.target.nodeName = FONT

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, styled-components

I am attempting to diagnose a very confusing bug in a production application. In a React application I have a list of buttons essentially like this:

```
const onClick = (event) => {
  // I expect event.target.dataset.name === option.name
}

<BaseButton onClick={onClick} data-name={option.name}>
  { option.text }
</BaseButton>
```

In the `onClick` handler I expect that `event.target.dataset.name === option.name` and in almost all cases that is correct. But occasionally the `target` is something else. In those cases `event.target.nodeName=FONT`.

I'm at a loss what this `FONT` node is and where it is coming from.

Comment: Have you tried using [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead?

Comment: Yeah that's currently the solution that I have and I'm likely to go with. But I'd still like to understand the behaviour that I'm seeing.